# Username in URL route configuration in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, routes

I am trying to create a custom route like this one mysite.com/username/controller/action/params. Basically after the user is authenticated to have its username appear in the url after the domain.

I tried the examples in the book but had no luck.

This is what I tried but was no help:
Router::connect('/:username/:controller/:action', array());
Router::connect('/:controller/:action', array());

Can you guys help me??

Thanks in advance,

Denis

Comment: Hi .. i have same problem .. did you solve this problem .. i need your help to solve my problem..

Comment: Hi, puzzled boy. Never solved this one, just gave up and started with Symfony.

Answer (score 3):

Cake doesn't automagically know what you mean with the `:username` parameter of your route. There are three default parameters that need no further configuration, those are:

1. `:controller`
2. `:action`
3. `:plugin`

All other parameters need to be specified with a matching regular expression and additionally you will need to specify an array called `pass` to tell Cake it should pass the parameter to your controller's action for this page. In your case, the route should probably look something like this:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:username/:controller/:action',
    array(), // Since you already have the controller and action in your URL there is no need for further directions here
    array(
        'pass' => array('username'), // If you want to pass the username to your action
        'username' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+' // What regex the username should match
    ),
);
```

Also see the book's page about Routing and specifically [this paragraph](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action) for further reference.

Comment: Hi oldskool, Thank you for the answer. I tried your example and read the book several times over, but still I have no luck, this route is not found by cakePHP. For example, in my layout I have an element which is using requestAction to retrieve the menu categories( categories/loadCategories ). When I add the user name to the URL, cake throws a missing controller and points to 'loadCategories' as being the missing controller. I am using CakePHP 2.0 if this is something specific to it. Thanks, Denis